# How to fill part of a cos/sine function

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a graph that plots sines and cosines and fills between the first cosine and the x-axis. However, I want the fill to run from x=1 in stead of x=0. However, I can't get this working without changing the cosine. How could this be achieved?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[very thick] (0,4.5)--(0,0);
\draw[very thick,] (0,0)--(14.5,0);
\draw[thick] (0,0) cos (2,2);
\draw[thick] (2,2) sin (4,4);
\draw[thick] (4,4) cos (6,2);
\draw[thick] (6,2) sin (7,1);
\draw[thick] (7,1) cos (8,2);
\draw[thick] (8,2) sin (10,4);
\draw[thick] (10,4) cos (12,2);
\draw[thick] (12,2) sin (14,0);

\fill[opacity=.2,color=black!30!green] (0,0) cos (2,2) -- (2,0) -- (0,0); 

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By clipping....

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[very thick] (0,4.5)--(0,0);
\draw[very thick,] (0,0)--(14.5,0);
\draw[thick] (0,0) cos (2,2);
\draw[thick] (2,2) sin (4,4);
\draw[thick] (4,4) cos (6,2);
\draw[thick] (6,2) sin (7,1);
\draw[thick] (7,1) cos (8,2);
\draw[thick] (8,2) sin (10,4);
\draw[thick] (10,4) cos (12,2);
\draw[thick] (12,2) sin (14,0);

\begin{scope}
\clip (1,0)--(2,0)--(2,2)--(1,2)--cycle;
\fill[opacity=.2,color=black!30!green] (0,0) cos (2,2) -- (2,0) -- (1,0); 
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As an aside, it's better to draw the curve after the fill in order not to overwrite one by the other.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another suggestion using the pgpflots library `fillbetween`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}% loads tikz too
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfdeclarelayer{pre main}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfsetlayers{pre main,main}
\path[very thick](0,0) edge (0,4.5) edge (14.5,0);
\draw[thick,name path=plot]
  (0,0) cos (2,2) sin (4,4) cos (6,2) sin (7,1)
  cos (8,2) sin (10,4) cos (12,2) sin (14,0);
\path[name path=xaxis](0,0)--(14,0);
\path[name path=clippath]
  (1,0|-current bounding box.south) rectangle (2,0|-current bounding box.north);
\tikzfillbetween[of=plot and xaxis,soft clip={clippath}]{opacity=.2,black!30!green}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]